# jQuery dragscroll plugin that works with links?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've got a design I'm working on and one of the things being pulled up is a list of buttons. I'd like this list to be click & drag to scroll, as it will be used on touch devices as well as desktop/laptops. I've found a few drag to scroll plugins, and even one I like very much for what I want to do ([azoffdesign overscroll](http://www.azoffdesign.com/overscroll)), but there will be limited space that isn't basically a link, so what I need is something like:

```
if(click and drag){
  no links;
  scroll vertical;
} else {
  links work normally;
}
```

I want to be able to click on a link, drag, and when I release the mouse, the link to not have taken effect (in this case I'm testing with `href=javascript:alert("lol")`)

Does anyone know of a jQuery plugin that does this?

Comment: What about using the middle mouse button for scrolling, and the left for clicking/selecting text? (Well some reasons for not doing that could be: 1) middle button used by various browser plugins, 2) people never use the middle button and quickly forget that they can use it on that particular page.)

Comment: Did you ever find a decent solution for this?